# Django App crashes when deployed to Heroku - Worker failed to boot

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku

Sorry for the long post but wanted to provide as much information as possible.

Having some serious issues trying to deploy a django app onto heroku.. Been battling for days with this.

The build is successful and so is the deployment but for some reason when navigating to the site address there is an application error.

wsgi.py

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "djangoProject.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

settings.py

```
import os
import dj_database_url

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
'users.apps.UsersConfig',
'crispy_forms',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djangoProject.urls'
enter code here
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djangoProject.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME':
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME':
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME':
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME':
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
USE_TLS = True
```

Error message from logs:

> 2018-12-02T04:24:16.294582+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294583+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294585+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294586+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294588+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294590+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294591+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294593+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294594+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294596+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294598+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294599+00:00 app[web.1]: **import**(module)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294601+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/djangoProject/wsgi.py", line 15, in 
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294602+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294604+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294605+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294607+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 19, in setup
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294608+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294610+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 57, in **getattr**
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294611+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294612+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 44, in _setup
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294614+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294615+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 107, in **init**
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294617+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294618+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294619+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294621+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/djangoProject/settings.py", line 27, in 
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294622+00:00 app[web.1]: DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294657+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError: name 'config' is not defined
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.294918+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-12-02 04:24:16 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298282+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-12-02 04:24:16 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298285+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298287+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298288+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298290+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298291+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298293+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298294+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298296+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298298+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298299+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298301+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298302+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298304+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298305+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298307+00:00 app[web.1]: **import**(module)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298308+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/djangoProject/wsgi.py", line 15, in 
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298310+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298311+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298313+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298314+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 19, in setup
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298316+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298317+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 57, in **getattr**
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298319+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298320+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 44, in _setup
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298322+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298323+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 107, in **init**
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298325+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298326+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298328+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298329+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/djangoProject/settings.py", line 27, in 
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298331+00:00 app[web.1]: DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298365+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError: name 'config' is not defined
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.298670+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-12-02 04:24:16 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.379203+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.379212+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 210, in run
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.379635+00:00 app[web.1]: self.sleep()
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.379667+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 360, in sleep
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.380038+00:00 app[web.1]: ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.380069+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 245, in handle_chld
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.380350+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.380384+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.380791+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.380959+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: 
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.380986+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.380988+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.380990+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.381018+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.381048+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in 
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.381251+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.381282+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 61, in run
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.381500+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.381539+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 223, in run
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.381822+00:00 app[web.1]: super(Application, self).run()
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.381852+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.382095+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.382125+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 232, in run
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.382399+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.382428+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 345, in halt
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.382782+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.382812+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.383169+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.383199+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 245, in handle_chld
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.383475+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.383505+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.383912+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.384052+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: 
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.525711+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
>   2018-12-02T04:24:16.509117+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
>   2018-12-02T04:26:07.329462+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=a5pire-django-framework.herokuapp.com request_id=bdd71320-3817-48e6-8667-78b6e4bc3c4b fwd="125.239.63.128" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Any help much appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: What does your procfile look like?

Comment: Just one line:

web: gunicorn djangoProject.wsgi --log-file -

Comment: Since the problem seems to be gunicorn related, you could try just web: gunicorn djangoProject.wsgi. Leave out --log-file. That's how my procfile is and the build is successful.

Comment: Thanks for the advice everyone. Will try the Procfile modification and report back.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this Probleme :

1) delete You're old requirement.txt
2) Make this Cmd pip freeze > requirements.txt
3) git add -A
4) git commit -m "last modification"
5) git push heroku master

6) And Finaly heroku open